# Rock Paper Scissors Javascript Game Add Choice Limit

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a Javascript-based Rock Paper Scissors game and it's pretty good so far. However, I want to create an option for "best out of 3" or "best out of 5". Please could some of you awesome JS people have a look at my code and see how I could implement the best of "x" scenario. Basically, I guess it comes down to the number of clicks.

Anyway, the code speaks for itself and here is a live example of the code:

[Rock Paper Scissors Live Github Example](https://rayanzenner.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/)

And the code:

```
(function(){

/*
 * Rock, paper, scissors  
 * 
 * The classic game recreated in Javascript for playing in the browser.
 * 
 */

// create the choices
var choices = [
    'rock',
    'paper',
    'scissors'
];

var CHOICES_LENGTH = choices.length;

// create the text for winning or drawing
var USER_WINS = "You win!";
var COMP_WINS = "Computer wins";
var DRAW = "Draw"

var MEH = '<i class="fa fa-meh-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
var SMILE = '<i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
var FROWN = '<i class="fa fa-frown-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

var score = 0;
var computer_score = 0;

var gameType;
var clicks = 0;

// score elements
var userScore = getById('score');
var compScore = getById('computerScore');

userScore.textContent = score;
compScore.textContent = computer_score;

// get the game area and get access to all the buttons
var game = getById('game');
var userChoices = game.getElementsByTagName('button');

var comp = getById('computer');
var compChoices = comp.getElementsByTagName('div');

// get the results element and hide it initially
var results = getById('results');
hide(results);

var gameOver = getById('gameOver');
hide(gameOver);

    // get the intro element and the buttons for choosing a game type
var intro = getById('intro');
var bestOf3 = getById('bestOf3');
var bestOf5 = getById('bestOf5');

// start the best of 3 game
bestOf3.onclick = function() {
    enableGame();
    gameType = 3;
}

bestOf5.onclick = function() {
    enableGame();
    gameType = 5;
}

function enableGame() {
    enable(userChoices);
    hide(intro);
}

// add an onclick event to each button and disable them initially
for(var i = 0; i < userChoices.length; i++) {
    userChoices[i].onclick = selection;
    userChoices[i].disabled = true;
}

function computerSelection() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * CHOICES_LENGTH);
    var compChoice = choices[randomIndex];
    return compChoice;
}

function selection() {
    // get the user and computer choice 
    var chosen = this.id;
    var comp = computerSelection();

    // get the users chosen item
    var chosenItem = getById(chosen);

    // prepare the chosenCompItem so we can assign it to a dynamic id
    var chosenCompItem;

    if(comp === 'rock') {
        chosenCompItem = getById('computerRock');
    } 
    else if(comp === 'paper') {
        chosenCompItem = getById('computerPaper');
    }
    else if(comp === 'scissors') {
        chosenCompItem = getById('computerScissors');
    }

    // show results and disable all choices so no more can 
    // be made while waiting for the pop up to fade out 
    show(results);
    reappear(results);
    disable(userChoices);
    disable(compChoices);


    // make the selected item stand out from the rest
    chosenItem.classList.add('selected');
    chosenCompItem.classList.add('selected');

    // decide who wins  


    if(chosen === comp) {
        results.textContent = DRAW;
        // ugly repetive code. what can I do???
        timeout();
        results.innerHTML += MEH;
    } 
    else if(chosen === 'rock' && comp === 'scissors') {
        results.textContent = USER_WINS;
        score += 1;
        userScore.textContent = score;
        timeout();
        results.innerHTML += SMILE;
    }
    else if(chosen === 'paper' && comp === 'rock') {
        results.textContent = USER_WINS;
        score += 1;
        userScore.textContent = score;
        timeout();
        results.innerHTML += SMILE;
    }
    else if(chosen === 'scissors' && comp === 'paper') {
        results.textContent = USER_WINS;
        score += 1;
        userScore.textContent = score;
        timeout();
        results.innerHTML += SMILE;
    }
    else {
        results.textContent = COMP_WINS;
        computer_score +=1;
        compScore.textContent = computer_score;
        timeout();
        results.innerHTML += FROWN;
    }


    console.log(clicks);
}


// utilities
function getById(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}   

function hide(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
}

function show(element) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
}

function disappear(element) {
    element.className = 'disappear';
}

function reappear(element) {
    element.className = 'reappear';
}

function disable(elements) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].disabled = true;
        elements[i].classList.add('unselected');
    }
}

function enable(elements) {
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].disabled = false;
        elements[i].classList.add('default');
        elements[i].classList.remove('selected', 'unselected');
    }
}

function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        disappear(results);
            enable(userChoices);
            enable(compChoices);
    }, 2000)
}
})();
```

The code has massive room for improvement but the main thing here is, how do I make it so the user gets only 3 or 5 plays??

Hope this all makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: I assume it's best of 3 wins / losses.  eg. Draws don't count.?.  If so in your timeout function, just add the computer score to the user score, if it equal gameType . game over.  `if(userScore + compScore === gameType) { gameOver(); }`

Comment: You already track the number of wins, so you're basically there already. For best of 3, end the game when someone's score reaches 2. For best of five, end at 3. If you go based on clicks, then draws would count against the end condition, and that is not how the game works IRL.

Comment: @Keith good points from both of you. Draws aren't counted in the real game so I would base it on wins! See if I can fix it from there. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your definition of best of "N" is the same as mine, my code should work.

My definition of "best of N" is:

> To win, one person must **win** N/2 rounds, with N/2 being rounded up to the nearest whole number.

You could use this code:

```
 if(userScore + compScore === gameType) { gameOver(); }
```

And use a simple `if` statement to see who won.

Hope this helped!

Comment: yep, that's essentially what I ended up doing thanks to the comments above. Thanks for helping